# downloading files with audio/mpeg mime type

Tags: php, http-headers, mime, readfile

I am trying to download ***remote*** mp3 files with an audio/mpeg mime type instead of right clicking on the link then saving as. I have tried modifying the header content-type with php headers and then calling the file with readfile(). This worked very well but because of the readfile() command the files came out of my servers bandwidth. is there another way of changing the header without the cost of bandwidth? can i define how the browser handles with content type with javascript? has anyone had the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to serve as download from where? Are the files located on a 3rd party server?

Comment: yep that is correct the files are on a 3rd party site eg i cannot modify the headers directly

Answer (score 1):

By using the mime type audio/mpeg you tell the browser to "do your default action with this file". In example if you have an jpg file and set the mime type to image/jpeg the browser will read the jpg and display it inside the browser window.

The solution is to use the mime type application/data instead. This will download the file leaving the browser out of it.

That would be

```
header("Content-type: application/data");
```

**== Updated ==**

A more complete approach

```
header("Content-type: application/data");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$this->filename");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
readfile($this->file);
```

If you want a dynamic mime type reader you could use this

```
$type = $this->get_mime_type($this->filename);
header("Content-type: " . $type);

...

private function get_mime_type($filename) {

    $fileext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);

    if (empty($fileext)) {
        return (false);
    }

    $regex = "/^([\w\+\-\.\/]+)\s+(\w+\s)*($fileext)/i";
    $lines = file("mime.types", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (substr($line, 0, 1) == '#') {
            continue; // skip comments
        }

        if (!preg_match($regex, $line, $matches)) {
            continue; // no match to the extension
        }

        return ($matches[1]);
    }
    return ("application/data");  // no match at all, revert to something that will work
}
```

And, to get a list of mime types you can check my lab version, save the displayed content and save it to a file named mime.types in the root of your website.

http://www.trikks.com/lab/mime.html

Have fun

Comment: All this results in is that the browser won't know what sort of file it is, so while it will force a download box, it isn't the right way to force a download. Use `Content-Disposition:` header instead...

Comment: Agree, Content-disposition with attachement is necessary as well but i thought that was a given. It's also nice to add a header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");

Comment: the only problem is because these files are remote files i can't directly alter the header i can only modify them, as stated in my question, but thank you for clearing up my confusion with headers and mime types

Comment: Ah, sorry for that, Updated my example with mime types a bit to clear the confusion. To remotely download files with php you should use either fsockopen or curl, here is a good sample http://www.awesomephp.com/?Tutorials*9/Download-a-remote-file-via-PHP.html

Comment: will fsock open and curl still come out of my server bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, php is a server side language and it cannot be in any other way when using it

Comment: so there is no way to download files from a remote site without first downloading them to my server, editing the header and then my server sending the file?

Comment: Not with any technique i'm aware of!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is this:

```
$pathOfAudioFile = '/path/to/my/file.mp3';

header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($pathOfAudioFile));

// This next line forces a download so you don't have to right click...
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($pathOfAudioFile).'"');

readfile($pathOfAudioFile);
```

Using `Content-Disposition: attachment...` forces a download box to appear instead of having to right click -> save target as.

Comment: but this will come out of my servers bandwidth with the readfile won't it?

Comment: It will, but how can you possibly download a file without it using up the server's bandwidth? You can't transfer data without using bandwidth... how are you wanting to avoid this?

Comment: the files im trying to download are remote files on a 3rd party site so i am wanting to avoid my server downloading those files to my server then uploading it my clients.

Comment: How do you want your client to recieve the file? as a download box or as an embedded player? and what happens when you go to the original site? do you get a download box or an embedded player?

Comment: here let me clear things up. there are files on remoteserver.com/some.mp3 which have audio/mpeg mime types. on my site clients download some.mp3 instead of streaming as the audio/mpeg mime specifies. is there a way for to download some.mp3 without my server downloading some.mp3, changing the header and then uploading it to the client eg can the client download some.mp3 from remoteserver.com instead of my site?

Comment: You can only do this at the client side, I.E. in Javascript. Have a look at an `<iframe>` combined with `document.execCommand('SaveAs','null','file.mp3');` although this is not supported everywhere - in fact it is only officially supported in IE.